# Copying file from network to Document Library

Tags: document-library, spfile

I'm trying to save file from network location to SharePoint document library.

This is code of my method:

```
//parameters: string documentLibraryUrl, string filePath

FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(filePath);
string fileName = fi.Name.Trim();       
using (SPSite oSite = new SPSite(documentLibraryUrl))
{
    using (SPWeb oWeb = oSite.OpenWeb())
    {
        SPFolder myLibrary = oWeb.GetFolder(documentLibraryUrl);

        // Prepare to upload
        using (FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead(filePath))
        {
            // Upload document

            SPFile spFile = oWeb.GetFile(myLibrary.Url + "/" + fileName);
            filePathInLibrary = spFile.ParentFolder.ServerRelativeUrl + "/" + fileName;
            spFile.SaveBinary(fileStream);      //this line throws exception

            // Commit 
            myLibrary.Update();

        }
    }
}
```

When I call `SPFile.SaveBinary`, I get following `DirectoryNotFoundException`:

```
<nativehr>0x80070003</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>There is no file with URL "http://localhost:9999/Lists/Documents/testfile.pdf" in this Website.
```

The `fileStream` variable is not null and has Length > 0. The list exists.

What could be wrong?

**So after Amit's reply, I changed the code from line:**

```
spFile.SaveBinary(fileStream);
```

to this block:

```
if (spFile.Exists)
{
    //do some logging here
}
else
{
    spFile = myLibrary.Files.Add(myLibrary.Url + "/" + fileName, fileStream);
}
```

In fact I get exactly the same error message on `myLibrary.Files.Add`.

**What else could be the reason of this error?** The code is probably correct, because it worked on different server. I'm thinking about permissions - can it be, that I need extra permissions on SharePoint or on SQL server? 
I'm able to add file to the list in UI (in browser) without problems. I'm using Claims Based Authentication. My user (with Windows identity) has Full Control permissions on Web Application.

Comment: For posterity, the line `if (spFile.Exists)` should not be used / depended upon for an existence check if you use `SPWeb.GetFile()` as the results of this property are inconsistent at best: http://blog.mastykarz.nl/inconvenient-spwebgetfilestring/

Comment: I'm getting this error using `SPWeb.GetFile` and the file definitely exists. Any luck on resolving?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all for your answers.
You wouldn't believe how silly and hard to find this error was.

The `myLibrary`'s Url was:

```xml
/Library/Documents
```

while the `siteUrl`, that was passed to my method was

```xml
http://localhost:9999/
```

This resulted in double slash between server name and list relative path.

Comment: You could use url combining to avoid these type of bugs: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/372865/path-combine-for-urls

Answer (score 3):

In above code `SPWeb.GetFile` don't give you a file as it does not exist (because you are copying a new file)

`SPFile.SaveBinary` is normally used to update exisitng file. To add a new file you should use `SPFolder.Files.Add`

Comment: I changed my code as you suggested, but unfortunately, I get the same error. See my update.

Answer (score 2):

please check this link it may helpfull to you

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/468469/how-do-you-upload-a-file-to-a-document-library-in-sharepoint

thanks